# Phonegap / Jquery Mobile unable to connect through proxy for http

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile, proxy

I use Chrome and Ripple to test my app don´t have any problem. But if I use my device (connect to PC) or emulator (Android) first request works fine but the second no.

I use cordova 2.0

My code:

```
      <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"                  
      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
      <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
      <head>
         <meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/">
      </head>
      <body></body> 
      </html>
```

the configuration of Local Area Network (Lan) Settings
Proxy Server:
Adress:10.0.32.5 Port:8080

Please, I need help to resolve this issue?

Comment: Have you followed [this domain whitelisting guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html#Domain%20Whitelist%20Guide)?

Comment: Yes, my configuration is : <access origin=".*"/> <!-- Allow all domains, suggested development use only -->

Comment: Why not just `"*"`? (Instead of `".*"`)

Comment: Ok, I changed but is the same behavior, Do you have another sugestion ? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='http://example.com/'">
```

See the quotes in the URL field.